# if ... then stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

I have an error in this stored procedure:

> Script line: 4    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INSERT INTO `escuelas_asignacion_maestro` (`idEscuela`,
>   `idCiclo`, `idGrado' at line 31

Code:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `zz73ff`.`pr_trasladar_asignaciones_por_ciclo` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `zz73ff`.`pr_trasladar_asignaciones_por_ciclo` 
(IN p_ciclo int, IN n_ciclo int)

BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE escuela, ciclo, grado, nGrupos, maestro INT;
DECLARE fecha datetime;
DECLARE cursor_asignaciones CURSOR FOR
SELECT idEscuela, idCiclo, idGrado, numeroGrupos, idMaestro FROM  escuelas_asignacion_maestro
WHERE idCiclo = p_ciclo
AND idEstatus = 1
ORDER BY idEscuela, idGrado;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

SELECT now() INTO fecha;

OPEN cursor_asignaciones;
REPEAT
FETCH cursor_asignaciones INTO escuela, ciclo, grado, nGrupos, maestro;

IF grado > 1 THEN

SELECT idEscuela, idCiclo, idGrado, numeroGrupos, idMaestro INTO
  escuela, ciclo, grado, nGrupos, maestro
FROM escuelas_asignacion_maestro
WHERE idCiclo = p_ciclo AND idEstatus = 1 AND idEscuela = escuela
  AND idGrado = (grado - 1);

 END IF

 INSERT INTO `escuelas_asignacion_maestro`
 (`idEscuela`, `idCiclo`, `idGrado`, `numeroGrupos`, `idEstatus`, `idMaestro`,          `fechaModificacion`)
  VALUES (escuela, n_ciclo, grado, nGrupos, 1,0, fecha);

  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cursor_asignaciones;

  END $$
  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: Did you try `END IF;` instead of `END IF`?